# Evaluation of these integrals

Tags: definite-integrals

I need a hint to evaluate the integrals:

$$ \int _{0}^{p}\tanh(\pi k)k\,dk\quad \text{and}\quad  \int _{0}^{s-1/2}\tan(\pi k)k\,dk $$
Here $p$ and $s$ are real numbers.

I know I can evaluate them by power series but how else can I evaluate these two integrals ?

I know I can expand $ \tanh(x) $ and $ \tan(x) $ into a power series but I would like to get some 'closed' result in terms of $ \Gamma (x) $ function or similar.

Comment: Result for the first integral returned by Mathematica 8 $$\text{ConditionalExpression}\left[\frac{\pi  p \left(\pi  p+2 \log \left(e^{-2 \pi 
   p}+1\right)\right)-\text{Li}_2\left(-e^{-2 p \pi }\right)}{2 \pi
   ^2}-\frac{1}{24},e^{-2 \pi  p}\geq -1\right]$$

Comment: Result for the second integral returned by Mathematica 8 $$\frac{i \left(3 \text{Li}_2\left(e^{2 i \pi  s}\right)+\pi  \left(\pi  \left(3 s^2-3
   s+1\right)+3 i (2 s-1) \log \left(1-e^{2 i \pi  s}\right)\right)\right)}{6 \pi ^2}$$

Comment: aha thanks.. :)

Comment: That is enough for you, or you need a _solution_ ?

Comment: I get this for integral one: Not sure if equivalent to `Norbet` answers. $\int_0^p \! ktanh(\pi k)=-(1/24)(-\pi^2+12p^2\pi^2-24p\ln(1+exp(2p\pi))\pi-12polylog(2,-exp(2p\pi)))/(\pi^2)$

Comment: @nightowl by hand?

Comment: @nightowl 7 edits, not bad ;-)

Comment: @draks: Of course not `:D`, using a CAS. Is it possible to get polylog function by hand or recognize it from doing intergrals? I just thought this was a CAS algorithmic way of deducing the problem into a more complex answer using special functions, because an elementary table look up failed. So it resorted to special solution techniques. Although $\tan k$ is considered a simple function but not sure about hyperbolic tangent `:)`

Comment: Damn... $  $ $  $ $  $